# jQuery - Why isn't this fadeout working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function Check() {
  $b = $('input[type=radio]:checked').val();
  $name = $('#InputBox').val();
  if ($name.length > 0 && typeof($b) != "undefined")
    $('.step_1_5').fadeOut(function() {
      $('.step_2').fadeIn();
    });
}
```

My problem is that even when the radio button is checked and the input box is filled in it still does nothing. I have some code in the middle but it's irrelevant as i've tested it and that part works fine. Thanks help appreciated! :)

How I called it:

```
 $('input[type=radio]').change(function()
 {
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
      Check();
 });
```

Comment: Are you sure `Check` is getting called when the radio button changes?

Comment: Make a fiddle please :)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/moquxowixi/edit?html,js,output Looks like it works to me

Comment: @MikeC added the call into post

Comment: @VigneshChinnaiyan It is not wrong to declare variables with "$". For example I use that so I know that variable has a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have reputation to leave a comment so I have to resort to posting as an answer. Perhaps posting your html will help us solve your problem as the posted jsbin seems to work. Another question that could help us solve your issue... What is your desired effect being When do you want the fade to happen 1) when the radio is checked or 2) when the input is filled?